# Function return type mismatch

Tags: fortran, gfortran, lapack, double-precision

I'm attempting to recode an old C++ program in Fortran to make use of LAPACK (I'm aware that C++ does have LAPACK++, but I'm having a lot of trouble installing it, so I gave up).

I originally didn't have any problems with compilation, but that was when I had all variables declared as `REAL`. When I started coding the section of the program that required LAPACK, I found that all parameters passed to `DSYEV` need to be `DOUBLE PRECISION`. So I tried to change everything to double precision (including changing all hard coded numbers to their double precision counterparts, i.e. 0.0 -> 0.0D0) Now when I try to compile, I get the following error for all of the functions and subroutines that I've written:

```
    Error: Return type mismatch of function <function> at (1) (REAL(4)/REAL(8))
```

I'm not sure where this is coming from, as everything in the program has been changed to double precision.

For example, I've declared the following:

```
double precision :: alpha(3),d(3),zeta1,zeta2
double precision :: A1(3),A2(3),D1(3),D2(3)
double precision :: PI
PI = 3.14159265359D0
alpha = (/0.109818D0, 0.405771D0, 2.22766D0/)
d = (/0.444635D0, 0.535328D0, 0.154329D0 /)

do 10 i=1,3

A1(i) = alpha(i)*zeta1**2.0D0
A2(i) = alpha(i)*zeta2**2.0D0
D1(i) = d(i)*(2.0D0*A1(i)/PI)**(3.0D0/4.0D0)
D2(i) = d(i)*(2.0D0*A2(i)/PI)**(3.0D0/4.0D0)

10  continue
```

And the function:

```
subroutine createS(S,A1,A2,D1,D2,r)
double precision A1(3),A2(3),D1(3),D2(3) 
double precision r
double precision S(2,2)
integer :: i,j
S(1,1) = 1.0D0
S(2,2) = 1.0D0
do 80 i=1,3
do 90 j=1,3

S(1,2) = S(1,2) + getS(A1(i),A2(j),r)*D1(i)*D2(j)

 90 continue
 80 continue
S(2,1) = S(1,2)
return
end

double precision function getS(a,b,r)
double precision :: PI
double precision a,b,r
double precision :: S
PI = 3.14159265359D0
S = (PI/(a+b))**1.5D0
S = S*dexp(-(a*b*r*r)/(a+b))
getS = S
return
end
```

And then I get the error

```
  HFSTO3G.f:85.28:

  S(1,2) = S(1,2) + getS(A1(i),A2(j),r)*D1(i)*D2(j)                 
                        1
  Error: Return type mismatch of function 'gets' at (1) (REAL(4)/REAL(8))
```

I'm using gfortran to compile. Could that be the issue? I'm not new to programming, but new to Fortran. Not programming this in Fortran is not an option.

Comment: there are also other libraries for C++ that do linear algebra, just to mention an alternative :)

Answer (score 5):

Did you put your subroutines and functions into a module and `use` that module?  Otherwise, probably what is occurring is that you are getting implicit typing of getS in subroutine createS as a single precision real but it actually returns a double precision.  Another suggestion: always use `implicit none` to find undeclared variable.  In case you forget to include `implicit none` in your source code, gfortran provides the compiler options `-fimplicit-none`. Implicit typing is pernicious and likely continued in Fortran to support legacy code.

P.S. `double precision` is also obsolete but much less risky than implicit typing.  If you have a recent version of gfortran you can use the following:

```
use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV
real (real64) ::
```

See the gfortran manual.

EDIT: The `implicit none` changed the type of getS from real(4) (by implicit typing) to unknown (no type declared, implicit typing disabled).   If you place the procedures into a module, they will "know" each others types: function returns and argument types.  This will fix this bug.  It also helps the compiler find other bugs but enabling it to check the consistency of arguments between the call and the arguments of the procedure.  See [Correct use of modules, subroutines and functions in fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412834/correct-use-of-modules-subroutines-and-functions-in-fortran) and [Computing the cross product of two vectors in Fortran 90](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511711/computing-the-cross-product-of-two-vectors-in-fortran-90/) for examples.

Comment: I did use implicit none on my one subroutine, but I just added it to all of the subroutines and functions, and now it gives me the same error, but instead of REAL(4)/REAL(8) on the error, it gives me UNKNOWN/REAL(8)

Comment: I expect that you are now getting a second error, that getS is undeclared in subroutine createS.  This is a clue to the problem.  It needs to be typed as double precision ... which you will automatically get by placing your routines in a module.

Answer (score 1):

You are not declaring `getS` as a function in the subroutine `createS`. You need to add `double precision, external :: getS` in your variable declarations of the subroutine `createS`.

Comment: My opinion: its best not to use `external` in modern Fortran.  If the function is in Fortran and you have the source code, put it into a module and `use` that module.  If it is in another language or it is in a library and you don't have the source code, then write an `interface` statement for it.  Both interface and module will give you argument consistency checking.  An explicit interface is required to use many "advanced" features of Fortran >=90.

Comment: I agree with this for **modern** Fortran, but the OP appears to be using F77, so I ran with what is common for that. (Though, if OP were posting F90+, I probably would recommend a simple `contains` within the subroutine `createS`).

Comment: Thanks for those comments. Why is it not recommended to use external?

Comment: @SimonDirmeier: I thought MSB's comment was sufficient, but you can see [this link](http://www.pcc.qub.ac.uk/tec/courses/f77tof90/stu-notes/f90studentMIF_4.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You simply do not declare the function in the main program
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGYdA.png)

Comment: Welcome, do not use pictures for code. Copy and paste all code as text and format it using the editor features. See [tour] and [answer].

Comment: Also, modern Fortran should use modules or internal functions. Not external functions, as already discussed after the answer by Kyle Kanos.