# Fortran - Declaring Recursive function in main program

Tags: fortran

Are we supposed to declare function names and type in the main program?

For example if i have a program named which has this header `recursive function sum(a,b) result(result)`

When i try to compile this, i get a few errors.

```
Error: Return type mismatch of function 'sum' at (1) (UNKNOWN/INTEGER(4))

Error: Function 'sum' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

I managed to get rid of the errors by declaring the function in the main program for example:

```
integer :: sum
```

Why does this happen? Are we always supposed to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place your procedures in modules and `use` the modules. You than have the so called `explicit interface` to the procedures an the code that uses the module knows the description of the procedures.

[Correct use of modules, subroutines and functions in fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412834/correct-use-of-modules-subroutines-and-functions-in-fortran)

When your function is not in a module, you indeed have to do what you shown, i.e., to declare

```
integer :: sum
```

This way the code knows `sum()` returns an integer. However it does not know what kind of arguments the function takes. The compiler cannot check if you use correct number and types of arguments when calling `sum()`.

When it is in a module, the compiler can check the arguments and you do not have to declare the return type again.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. I have a doubt, like in C, does it matter if the program is above the function or the function is above the program?

Comment: No, in C the compilation unit is the file. In Fortran the compilation units are the main program, modules and external procedures and they are compiled separately. It does not suffice that the function is in the same source file.

Comment: If you use modules, they must be compiled  first before using them. They can be in the same file, but must be at the top.