# Solving a linear system with the Gauss method returns wrong results

Tags: fortran, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, fortran90

**Thank you guys, all your advices are relevant, but I gave up of Fortran and translated my code to Python. There, with just 1 or 2 little bugs my code worked perfect**

I wrote a program to solve a linear system using the Gauss method. I wrote all the algorithms, the forward elimination and the back substitution and I made a lot of others subroutines and I don't know anymore what's wrong, I don't if is something wrong with my code or if some problem programming in Fortran because I'm new in this language. I'll put my code below and the linear system that I should find a solution

```
PROGRAM metodo_Gauss
    IMPLICIT NONE

    REAL :: det_a_piv
    INTEGER :: n, i, j
    REAL, DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: a, a_piv 
    INTEGER, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: p 
    REAL, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: b, x 

    PRINT*, "Entre com a dimensão n do sistema a ser resolvido"
    READ*, n

    ! allocate memory
    ALLOCATE(a(n, n))
    ALLOCATE(a_piv(n, n))
    ALLOCATE(p(n))
    ALLOCATE(b(n))
    ALLOCATE(x(n))

    CALL matriz_a(n, a)
    CALL vetor_b(n, b)

    a_piv(1:n, 1:n) = a(1:n, 1:n)

    DO i = 1, n
        x(i) = 0
    END DO

    CALL eliminacao(n, a, a_piv, p)

    det_a_piv = (-1) ** n
    DO j = 1, n
        det_a_piv = det_a_piv * a_piv(j, j)
    END DO

    IF (det_a_piv == 0) THEN

        PRINT*, "O sistema linear é indeterminado"

    ELSE IF (abs(det_a_piv) <= 1) THEN

        PRINT*, "O sistema linear é mal-condicionado"
    ELSE

        CALL substituicao(n, a_piv, p, b, x)
        PRINT*, "A solução do sistema é:"
        PRINT*, x
    END IF

END PROGRAM metodo_Gauss

SUBROUTINE matriz_a(n, a)
    IMPLICIT NONE

        INTEGER, INTENT(in) :: n
        REAL, DIMENSION(n,n), INTENT(inout) :: a


        INTEGER :: i, j !Indícios usados em loops para percorrer os arrays

    PRINT*, "Por favor digite os valores do elementos da matriz sistema linear seguindo pela ordem das linhas até o final:"

        DO i = 1, n
            DO j = 1, n
                READ*, a(i,j)
            END DO
        END DO

END SUBROUTINE matriz_a

SUBROUTINE vetor_b(n, b)
    IMPLICIT NONE

    INTEGER, INTENT(in) :: n
    REAL, DIMENSION(n), INTENT(inout) :: b

    INTEGER :: i 

    PRINT*, "Por favor entre com os elementos do vetor b:"

    DO i = 1, n
        READ*, b(i)
    END DO

END SUBROUTINE vetor_b

SUBROUTINE eliminacao(n, a, a_piv, p)
    IMPLICIT NONE


    INTEGER, INTENT(in) :: n
    REAL, DIMENSION(n, n), INTENT(in) :: a
    REAL, DIMENSION(n, n), INTENT(out) :: a_piv
    INTEGER, DIMENSION(n), INTENT(out) :: p


    INTEGER :: i, j, local, dim 
    REAL :: mult 

    DO i = 1, (n - 1)

        dim = n - 1

        CALL local_pivo(dim, a(i:n, i), local)

        a_piv(i, i:n) = a(local, i:n)
        a_piv(local, i:n) = a(i, i:n)

        p(i) = local

        DO j = (i + 1), n
                mult = (-1) * (a_piv(j,i) / a_piv(local,i))
                a_piv(j,i) = mult
                a_piv(j, j:n) = a_piv(j, j:n) + mult * a_piv(i, j:n)
        END DO

    END DO

END SUBROUTINE eliminacao

SUBROUTINE local_pivo(n, a, local)
    IMPLICIT NONE

    INTEGER, INTENT(in) :: n
    REAL, DIMENSION(n), INTENT(in) :: a
    INTEGER, INTENT(inout) :: local

    INTEGER :: i 

    local = 1


    DO i = 2, n
        IF ((ABS(a(i))) > ABS(a(local))) THEN
            local = i
        END IF
    END DO

END SUBROUTINE local_pivo

SUBROUTINE substituicao(n, a_piv, p, b, x)
    IMPLICIT NONE


    INTEGER, INTENT(in) :: n
    REAL, DIMENSION(n, n), INTENT(in) :: a_piv
    REAL, DIMENSION(n), INTENT(out) :: b, x
    INTEGER, DIMENSION(n), INTENT(in) :: p


    INTEGER :: i, j, k, l, pivo 
    REAL :: aux 


    DO i = 1, (n - 1)


        pivo = p(i)


        IF (pivo /= i) THEN
            aux = b(i)
            b(i) = b(pivo)
            b(pivo) = aux
        END IF

        DO j = (i + 1), n
            b(j) = a_piv(j, i) * b(j) + b(i)
        END DO

    END DO

    DO k = n, 1, -1
        IF (k == n) THEN
            x(n) = b(n) / a_piv(n, n)
        ELSE
            x(k) = (b(k) + a_piv(k, n) * x(n)) / a_piv(k, k)
            DO l = n, k, -1
                x(l) = x(l) + (a_piv(k, l) * x(l)) / a_piv(k, k)
            END DO
        END IF
    END DO



END SUBROUTINE substituicao
```

Here it is the system that I'm trying to solve

[image]

My input is:

```
4

4
3
2
2
2
1
1
2
2
2
2
4
6
1
1
2

5
8
3
1
```

My output is:

```
-40.5000000      -40.2500000      -3.75000000      -37.5000000
```

But the output should be:

```
6.500000
-44.000000
72.000000
-16.500000
```

Comment: What is the output you get, what are the problems?

Comment: The output is giving me an array vector with elements all negatives and low numbers. It's not the linear system soluction. I don't know what are the problems, i already made a lot of changes

Comment: Please add the result in the question and also the numbers you inputted into the program (probably 4 4 2 2 6 3 ....)

Comment: i did it now, please help me D:

Comment: You should, before you do anything else, put all your subroutines either into a module and *use-associate* them; or include them, in the same source file as the program, in a `contains` section.  Either of these will enable the compiler to check that the subroutine calls match their expected signatures.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412834/correct-use-of-modules-subroutines-and-functions-in-fortran for more on the topic, other questions and answers too.

Comment: This is not the error, i tried to do the INTERFACE that its de contains for subroutines and i had a lot of bugs

Comment: Perhaps the fact that you found a lot of bugs when trying to implement features that check your code indicate that your code has a lot of bugs?

Comment: okay, challenge accepted

Comment: tha bugs are all about assignments...

Comment: It's probably not the what is causing the problem, but you have the intent for b wrong in the substituicao routine, it should be InOut, not Out.

Comment: Two comments; 1) your matrix is singular, `det(A)=0`,  2) just out of curiosity, why are you trying to reinvent the wheel? Is it for educational purpose? My knowledge is that a lot of subroutines exist for solving this problem, have you checked math libraries written decades ago for solving this?

Comment: Check your code on simple 2x2 matrix and find the issue this way.

Comment: @AboAmmar The matrix should not be singular - [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Det%7B%7B4%2C+3%2C+2%2C+2%7D%2C+%7B2%2C+1%2C+1%2C+2%7D%2C+%7B2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+4%7D%2C+%7B6%2C+1%2C+1%2C+4%7D%7D+)

Comment: Note there is a difference between the image and the input data, bottom right element of the matrix!

Comment: One problem is that in the `eliminacao` procedure, just before calling `local_pivo()`, you incorrectly set `dim=n-1`, instead it needs to be `dim=n-i+1`. There may still be other errors. Generally, I would recommend to set `n` inside `local_pivo` as `n=size(a)`, which is safer and cleaner. Similarly, I would use this everywhere else.

Comment: Your input looks like it is listed as row major, and I am pretty sure fortran is column major... that could be an explation for the main problem.

Comment: @IanBush you're right, i changed the intent to inout in this routine

Comment: @AboAmmar the matrix isnt singular, but okay, ive already translated my code to python and everything gone well hahahahha it's for my numerical methods classes, and i'm studying physics that needs a lot of algorithms to do the models, its always important to know what goes on in the process

Comment: @rpoleski good advice, thank you, i'll try this

Comment: @PetrH you are right, i tried to make the dim=n-i+1 but how the bugs were still there i thought this was not the problem, but thats the right logical. Thank you for the advice, ill try to set n=size(a) later

Comment: @Holmz im totally lost in fortran, i'm starting to use now and im totally confuse with matrix, because i use to work with arrays only in python, and fortran also is a stone age language hahahahhaa i dont know why the hell the teacher want us to use fortran omg

Comment: Because Fortran is typically around 10 to 100 times faster than python for real work

Comment: @IanBush Some of the Python is fast as fortran. At least the Python written in fortran seems to have the same performance.

Comment: @Giovana don't complain about the teacher... my question was whether the data as show in the post, is intended to be row or column major?